# Xcode-How to make the objects are aligned along the edge of the screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, autolayout

I want that buttons were placed from edge of display to edge display. I use autolayout, but blue frames limit my buttons. I pasted the link of screenshots. I cannot load on site, I haven't 10 reputation. Please help.
Thanks.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jmf6ks2osqfxczg/AAAwXUBX3B4GbICM1Z17NBs7a?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck *Constrain to margins* when you pin the buttons.  Make sure the offsets are `0`.